# PHP: Display Graph and some data besides to the graph

Tags: php

I  am trying to write code which generates graph and some data both on same webpage, individual code is working fine, can someone please help me with coding, I am trying to display graph then trying to print avg value of yaxis or sql column.

e->autoOutput("pictures/example.drawBarChart.spacing.png");

Comment: Your code is somewhat messy, there is a missing quote in your sql statement, a "enter code here" in the second code block and a magic quote after the "echo $average;" line. What's the problem by the way? It's not working or you need the implementation?

Comment: Looking for implementation, don't worry about sql statement part, I just need to write code so that I can display graph and print $average